# responsiveflex layout wrapping issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I got a problem with a special responsive flex layout.
My goal:[image: responsive flex layout]

Container 2 can have a static with.
I already tested a few possible solutions:

- float container 2 right on desktop
- set absolute position for container 2 on desktop.

Is there a more flexible solution that doesn't use float or absolute positioning?

Comment: where are tried code  ??

Comment: FYI, the flex tag is for Flash questions (Adobe Flex).  Use "flexbox" for CSS questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox` if you have fixed height on your container element. Then you just need to change order of elements with media queries.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.a {
  background: #2873FD;
}
.b {
  background: #C015FF;
}
.c {
  background: #15FF78;
}
@media(min-width: 480px) {
  .a, .c {
    order: 1;
    flex: 0 0 30%;
  }
  .b {
    order: 2;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .content > div {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess that will do it